# Is there a way to inherit the [Required] attribute from the parent when doing Data-Annotation validation in ASP.NET MVC 5?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, data-annotations

I am trying to build an application on the top of Asp.Net MVC 5 framework.

I have a view model called `TaskViewModel` a simplified version of it looks like so

```
public class TaskViewModel
{
    [Required]
    public ReasonViewModel Reasons { get; set; }
    //......
}
```

The `ReasonViewModel` class is a partial View-Model that is used to encapsulate the (available-options and the selected options). Additionally, it allows me to create reusable `EditorTemplate` for it,

The `ReasonViewModel` class look something like this

```
public class ReasonViewModel
{
    [Required]
    public int? Id { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Options { get; set; }

    public TaskStatusReasonViewModel()
    {
        if(Options == null)
        {
            var options = new List<SelectListItem>();

            options.Add(SelectListItem
                        {
                            ///...
                        })

            Options = options;
        }
    }
}
```

This is working great as I am able to define editor-template called `ReasonViewModel.cshtml` and I can render this view-model easily using `Html.EditorFor` or `Html.Editor()`

The problem here is that the `Id` property is always required. If a different view-model want to use the `ReasonViewModel` but does not required the `Id` property to be `Required` then my setup is no longer flexible :(

I know I can make yet another partial view-model and call it something like `OptionalReasonViewModel` to look like so

```
public class OptionalReasonViewModel : ReasonViewModel
{
    new public int? Id { get; set; }
}
```

I should be able to solve this problem using something like so

```
public class OptionalTaskViewModel
{
    [DataType("ReasonViewModel")]
    public OptionalReasonViewModel Reasons { get; set; }
    //......
}
```

As you can see, I would have to create a secondary partial view for every partial view to work around this problem.

However, if there is a way to tell the property to inherit its value from it's parent then I won't have to duplicate my partial view-model.

In another words if I can do the following

```
public class ReasonViewModel
{
    [Required(Inherit)] // The Inherit is something I made up here
    public int? Id { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Options { get; set; }

    public TaskStatusReasonViewModel()
    {
        if(Options == null)
        {
            var options = new List<SelectListItem>();

            options.Add(SelectListItem
                        {
                            ///...
                        })

            Options = options;
        }
    }
}
```

Then when I want the `Reasons.Id` property to be required, then I would decorate the caller property using the `Required` attribute which would tell the partial model-view to make any property that is decorated with `[Required(Inherit)]` required.

```
public class TaskViewModel
{
    [Required]
    public ReasonViewModel Reasons { get; set; }
    //......
}
```

And when I want don't want the `Reasons.Id` property to be required, then I would not decorate the caller property using the `Required` attribute which would tell the partial model-view to make any property that is decorated with `[Required(Inherit)]` not required.

```
public class OptionalTaskViewModel
{
    public ReasonViewModel Reasons { get; set; }
    //......
}
```

Is it possible to make the `Required` attribute inherit it's value from the called property? If so, how?

Comment: Are you worried about the validation that happens on the client and/or when it comes back to your controller method?

Comment: You could apply aconditional validation attribute (e.g. a [foolproof](https://github.com/leniel/foolproof) `[RequiredIf]` so validation is only based on another property (e.g. a `bool IsIdRequired`)

Comment: @ErikPhilips in a perfect world, the same validation rule will be applied on both client and server side. So if the parent class is defining it as required then make it required on both client/server side otherwise no.

Comment: Then this question seems like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8991346/mvc-architecture-re-using-the-same-viewmodel-for-reads-and-edits/8991547#8991547

Comment: Can you break your view models up to multiple classes? Perhaps create a new view model titled IdentityViewModel with only the required id attribute. Then, optionally inherit from it if the id attribute is applicable.